# uploading app problem in developers site

Tags: java, android

hi i have posted one of my app in market.android.com when i am trying to post second app it shows "You have another application on Market with the same package name. Go to that other application, and click upgrade" I dont want to upgrade it but i want my second app to be posted. When i tried to change the package name it showed lots of errors, so i decided to create the app once again in a new package and project name, it seems to be a very lengthy process.... pls help me to solve the issue bcoz i have created all my app in same package name unknowingly.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you have no option but to change the package name. The market uses the package name to uniquely identify your app so you cannot have two different apps with the same package name since they are considered to be the same app.

If you are using Eclipse, you should be able to rename the package (select your package name in the project explorer, and press F2) and refactor your app easily enough though.

You will have to be aware next time to use a different package name.

Comment: yes i am using eclipse but i am not able to find that project explore, pls guide me

Comment: There's a quick guide [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7836343_change-package-name-eclipse.html)

Comment: No problem, you might get one or two issues left over with the refactoring (when I've done this, it doesn't always update the manifest, for example), but they're a lot easier to deal with than manually refactoring.

Comment: ya i have the problem pls say me about it

Comment: You will need to open your manifest.xml, and change the old package name for the new one.

Comment: i have changed but the problem is it is not extracting the jar files and in the source codes import.(firstpackage name).R is been marked as error and i change it to new package name but no use....

Comment: Ah, yes - you should be able to just comment out those import lines, you don't need them.